# How to make nearly perfect assumption of $ x_0 $ to proceed further with Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I'm writing my own RealNumber class in Python, where I need to get the $ n $-th root of $ M $. Here, $ n, M \in \mathbb{Z}^+. $

I'm trying to follow the Newton-Raphson method for calculation of the $ n $-th root.

Input to my function: M - a positive integer, n - root needs to find of M.

$ f(x) = x^n - M $, $ f'(x) = nx^{n-1} $

Now I need to first calculate the $ x_0 $, so that, $ x_{i+1} = x_i - \frac{x_i^n - M}{nx_i^{n-1}} $.

But, how can I assume the $ x_0 $ for every $ n $ and $ M $ provided?

Comment: (This comment is for floating point implementations.)  What about range reduction? $\sqrt[n]{M} = \sqrt[n]{M / b^{nk}} \times b^k$, pick $k$ to make the input to the "actual" root implementation be in a convenient range (e.g. near $1$), where you can pick $x_0$ more easily.  $b$ is typically $2$ for binary, might be $10$ if your implementation is decimal.  Division/multiplication by $b^m$ can be done by subtracting/adding $m$ to the exponent.

Comment: Thanks @Claude!

Answer (score 1):

In a general manner, when you use Newton method for the solution of $f(x)=0$, provided that its second derivative does not change sign, if you want the smoothest path to solution (that is to say no overshoot), select $x_0$ such that
$$f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) ~> ~0$$

This is [Darboux theorem](http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf)

For your case, since $f''(x)>0$, start above the solution.

Take the example where $M=123456789$ and $n=5$ with two different starting points

- **Bad case**

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & x_k \\
 0 & 20.0000 \\
 1 & 170.321 \\
 2 & 136.286 \\
 3 & 109.100 \\
 4 & 87.4547 \\
 5 & 70.3858 \\
 6 & 57.3147 \\
 7 & 48.1399 \\
 8 & 43.1094 \\
 9 & 41.6367 \\
 10 & 41.5250 \\
 11 & 41.5244 \\
 12 & 41.5244 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

- **Good case**

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & x_k \\
 0 & 60.0000 \\
 1 & 49.9052 \\
 2 & 43.9049 \\
 3 & 41.7689 \\
 4 & 41.5272 \\
 5 & 41.5244 \\
 6 & 41.5244 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hey Leibovici! Thanks for your solution. But, can you please tell me why you started from 20.0000 and 60.0000?? I don't get that point.

Comment: @DebtanuGupta. Just to show a bad starting point and a good one.